# Write file error handling

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

just a short question about writing into a file in C++. Everything is written into the file when i use the file.close(); command and not before. So I only have to check, if the file could be opened and also if the close command was working. Is this enough for error handling in C++ using ofstream?

Cheers

Comment: It's not true that the data is only written to the file when calling `close()`. If that's what you're seeing, you're probably witnessing some buffering in action. Try disabling buffering or calling `flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You need to check errors after the individual writes as well.  As @FrerichRaabe said, the writes actually do happen before the file.close().  However, you may not see those writes happen because of buffering.  But errors can happen at other times as well.

Comment: ok, so I have to check each time i use file.write(char, length); e.g.: file.write(char1, length1); if(file.fail()){//error}; file.write(char2, length2); if(file.fail()){//error};
is there a better solution?